# Changing OS destroying my game FPS (Java Slick 2D)

Tags: java, linux, windows, slick2d, frame-rate

recently changed my HDD to a SSD and my windows 7 into a linux ubuntu 14.4.

I was developping a game (a pretty simple but still nice and addictive one) on Eclipse, using the Java language and the Slick 2D library.

On Windows my game ran at an average 300 fps, which was correct and playable. It just had some lags, but it wasn't that bad.

Now that I had my new Linux, the first thing I did was using an apt-gest install eclipse, and then I imported my project, linked the JARs and natives, and.. Had to enable the FPS show again to notice that it was running with 30 FPS, which isn't playable at all. Can somebody tell me what could be wrong ?

Comment: Native libraries for linux are not well optimized as windows' maybe?

Comment: Three words:  open source drivers.  You're going to get a lot less performance from those than you are with the official vendor drivers.

Comment: I don't feel like the problem comes from natives. I'll try to get a "real" install of Eclipse to see if the problem comes from the install, thanks :)